Getting previous month's existing student count if there are no new adds this month
I have a table with student data which includes their start and withdrawal dates. Not all students have withdrawal dates as they are still enrolled.
I am trying to calculate the number of new students per month, withdrawals per month, existing students per month. I have already completed counts of new and withdrawals per month, I am facing trouble in the calculation of existing students.
Data starts from January 2023.
This is the query I have come up with:
WITH student_activity AS 
(
    -- Convert start and withdrawal date keys to actual date format
    SELECT to_date(fe.start_date_key::text, 'YYYYMMDD') AS start_date,
    to_date(fe.withdrawal_date_key::text, 'YYYYMMDD') AS withdrawal_date,
    dp.product_name, dp.sku
    FROM fact_enrolment fe
    INNER JOIN dim_product dp ON fe.product_key = dp.product_key
)
SELECT date_trunc('month', month_series) AS month,
COUNT(*) AS existing_students,
sa.product_name
FROM (
    SELECT generate_series(
    (SELECT MIN(to_date(start_date_key::text, 'YYYYMMDD')) FROM fact_enrolment),'2100-12-31',INTERVAL '1 month') AS month_series) AS months
LEFT JOIN student_activity sa ON sa.start_date < month_series AND (sa.withdrawal_date IS NULL OR sa.withdrawal_date >= month_series)
GROUP BY month, sa.product_name

This query does get the existing counts correctly but I am facing an issue where if a month does not have students starting in it, then the month is not displayed at all in the result set. I need it to still display each month and if it does not have any new values to it, then it should use the previous month's count as those students are still enrolled.
CREATE TABLE fact_enrolment (
    student_key int4 NULL,
    start_date_key int4 NULL,
    withdrawal_date_key int4 NULL,
    product_key int4 NULL);

CREATE TABLE dim_product (
    product_key int4 GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY( INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 START 1 CACHE 1 NO CYCLE) NOT NULL,
    product_name varchar NULL,
    sku varchar NULL);

INSERT INTO dim_product (product_name , sku) VALUES ('Preschool' , 'ABC123');

INSERT INTO fact_enrolment (student_key, start_date_key, withdrawal_date_key, product_key) VALUES 
  (12, 20230105, 20230130, 1)
, (14, 20230106, 20230120, 1)
, (45, 20230405, 20230420, 1);
INSERT INTO fact_enrolment (student_key, start_date_key, product_key) VALUES 
  (17, 20230110, 1)
, (20, 20230120, 1)
, (21, 20230220, 1)
, (22, 20230202, 1)
, (23, 20230228, 1)
, (34, 20230206, 1)
, (44, 20230406, 1);

Calculations based on the sample given:



month
adds
withdrawals
existing students




2023-01
4
2
4


2023-02
4
0
6


2023-03
0
0
6


2023-04
2
1
8



Assuming that the withdrawals happen at the end of the month in the above table, they are subtracted in the next month's count.
In the example to note 2023-03 is still shown with the previous month's count.
I am using Postgres version 13.15.

You can use aggregate filter clause to count(*) different things in a single aggregated query. Window functions then let you run two stepping sums of those counts and subtract them to get current balance.
demo at db<>fiddle
WITH student_activity AS (-- Convert start and withdrawal date keys to actual date format
    SELECT date_trunc('month',to_date(fe.start_date_key::text, 'YYYYMMDD'))::date AS start_month
         , date_trunc('month',to_date(fe.withdrawal_date_key::text, 'YYYYMMDD'))::date AS withdrawal_month
         , dp.product_name
         , dp.sku
    FROM fact_enrolment AS fe
    JOIN dim_product AS dp 
      ON fe.product_key = dp.product_key )
,calendar as (
    select month::date
    from (select min(start_month) as earliest_month
               , max(start_month) as latest_month
          from student_activity) as limits
    cross join lateral generate_series(earliest_month,latest_month,'1 month'::interval) as month)
,monthly_balance as (
    select month
         , count(*)filter(where month=start_month) as enrollments
         , count(*)filter(where month=withdrawal_month) as withdrawals
    from calendar
    left join student_activity as fe
    on month=any(array[start_month,withdrawal_month]) 
    group by month)
select*, sum(enrollments)over w1
        -sum(withdrawals)over w1 as "existing students"
from monthly_balance
window w1 as(order by month)
order by month;

I'm not sure why after 10 students enrolled and 3 withdrew, you expect to be left with 8. That's 7:



month
enrollments
withdrawals
existing students




2023-01-01
4
2
2


2023-02-01
4
0
6


2023-03-01
0
0
6


2023-04-01
2
1
7




@ValNik Good point, thanks. Post and demo edited.

The OP's approach is not entirely clear, but perhaps the option greatest(max(start_month),max(withdrawal_month)) as latest_month will be more reliable.

You need to create "date_spine" dataset that You can use as Your main table during the joins.
WITH 
date_spine AS (
  --this will generate date spine with all months from given range
  --this will be used as main table to join as we need all months from here
  SELECT 
    distinct 
      to_char(day, 'YYYY-MM') as spine_month
  FROM generate_series
          ( '2023-01-01'::timestamp, '2030-12-01'::timestamp, '1 day'::interval) day
),
student_activity AS (
  --cleans data table with student activities
  --converts dates to YYYY-MM format string, which will later be used to join to data spine
  SELECT
    student_key,
    to_char(to_date(fe.start_date_key::text, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY-MM') as start_month,
    coalesce(to_char(to_date(fe.withdrawal_date_key::text, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYY-MM'), '2999-12') as withdrawal_month
  FROM fact_enrolment fe
),
adds AS (
  --calculates number of new students in given month
  select
    start_month,
    count(*) as adds
  from student_activity
  group by start_month
),
withdrawals AS (
  --calculates number of withdrawals in given month
  select
    withdrawal_month,
    count(*) as withdrawals
  from student_activity
  group by withdrawal_month
),
existing_students AS (
  --calculates number of 'active' students during each month of data spine
  --this assumes that if a student start and withdrawal is in same month such student will be counted as existing in given month
  select 
    count(student_activity.student_key) as existing_students,
    date_spine.spine_month
  from date_spine
  left join student_activity 
    on date_spine.spine_month between student_activity.start_month and student_activity.withdrawal_month
  group by date_spine.spine_month
),
joins AS (
  --joins data spine with adds, withdrawals and existing students
  select 
    date_spine.spine_month as month,
    coalesce(adds.adds, 0) as adds,
    coalesce(withdrawals.withdrawals, 0) as withdrawals,
    coalesce(existing_students.existing_students, 0) as existing_students
  from date_spine
  left join adds on date_spine.spine_month = adds.start_month
  left join withdrawals on date_spine.spine_month = withdrawals.withdrawal_month
  left join existing_students on date_spine.spine_month = existing_students.spine_month
)
select * from joins order by month

The result that You will get is like below:
 month  | adds | withdrawals | existing_students 
---------+------+-------------+-------------------
 2023-01 |    4 |           2 |                 4
 2023-02 |    4 |           0 |                 6
 2023-03 |    0 |           0 |                 6
 2023-04 |    2 |           1 |                 8
 2023-05 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2023-06 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2023-07 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2023-08 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2023-09 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2023-10 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2023-11 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2023-12 |    0 |           0 |                 7
...
 2029-12 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2030-01 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2030-02 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2030-03 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2030-04 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2030-05 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2030-06 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2030-07 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2030-08 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2030-09 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2030-10 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2030-11 |    0 |           0 |                 7
 2030-12 |    0 |           0 |                 7


It seemed to me that recursively adding missing rows in the report by months in which there are no events is quite an economical approach. I suppose there are few such empty months. In some cases, this may be preferable to using a calendar table.
Adds start_date_key is moved to beginning of the month, for grouping by this date as key.
date_trunc('month',to_date((start_date_key)::text, 'YYYYMMDD'))::date

Also, the "withdrawal" events are transferred to the next month's report, since these students were somehow present this month and they do not need to be excluded from the count this month.
date_trunc('month',to_date((withdrawal_date_key)::text, 'YYYYMMDD')+ interval '1 month')::date

See example
Example data with some added rows:



student_key
start_date_key
withdrawal_date_key
product_key




12
20230105
20230130
1


14
20230106
20230120
1


17
20230110
null
1


20
20230120
null
1


22
20230202
null
1


34
20230206
null
1


21
20230220
null
1


23
20230228
null
1


45
20230405
20230420
1


44
20230406
null
1


55
20240306
null
1


56
20240406
null
1


57
20240505
20240831
1


58
20240531
20240531
1



with recursive starts as( -- all events with new report_date (td)
select product_key,'s' fl,start_date_key
  ,date_trunc('month',to_date((start_date_key)::text, 'YYYYMMDD'))::date td
from fact_enrolment t
  union all
select product_key,'w' fl,withdrawal_date_key
  ,date_trunc('month',to_date((withdrawal_date_key)::text, 'YYYYMMDD')+ interval '1 month')::date td
from fact_enrolment t
where withdrawal_date_key is not null
)
,totals as ( -- totals and running sums
select product_key,td
  ,sum(case when fl='s' then 1 else 0 end) ns
  ,sum(case when fl='s' then 0 else 1 end) nw
  ,sum(sum(case when fl='s' then 1 else 0 end))
      over(partition by product_key order by td) tns
  ,sum(sum(case when fl='s' then 0 else 1 end))
      over(partition by product_key order by td) tnw
  ,lead(td,1,td)over(partition by product_key order by td) next_td
from starts
group by product_key,td
)
,r as (
select product_key,td
  ,td rdt
  ,ns,nw,tns,tnw, tns-tnw rest, next_td 
from totals
  union all
select product_key,td
  ,(rdt+interval '1 month')::date
  ,0 ns,0 nw,tns,tnw,rest, next_td 
from r
where (rdt+interval '1 month')::date<next_td
)
select product_key,rdt report_date, ns adds,nw withdrawals
  , rest existing_students,tns total_adds, tnw total_withdrawal
from r order by rdt





product_key
report_date
adds
withdrawals
existing_students
total_adds
total_withdrawal




1
2023-01-01
4
0
4
4
0


1
2023-02-01
4
2
6
8
2


1
2023-03-01
0
0
6
8
2


1
2023-04-01
2
0
8
10
2


1
2023-05-01
0
1
7
10
3


1
2023-06-01
0
0
7
10
3


1
2023-07-01
0
0
7
10
3


1
2023-08-01
0
0
7
10
3


1
2023-09-01
0
0
7
10
3


1
2023-10-01
0
0
7
10
3


1
2023-11-01
0
0
7
10
3


1
2023-12-01
0
0
7
10
3


1
2024-01-01
0
0
7
10
3


1
2024-02-01
0
0
7
10
3


1
2024-03-01
1
0
8
11
3


1
2024-04-01
1
0
9
12
3


1
2024-05-01
2
0
11
14
3


1
2024-06-01
0
1
10
14
4


1
2024-07-01
0
0
10
14
4


1
2024-08-01
0
0
10
14
4


1
2024-09-01
0
1
9
14
5



fiddle
